# How to change postgresql.conf file using command prompt?

Tags: postgresql

I want to change some configurations in postgresql.conf file using command prompt. I have tried `Alter System` but every time ask for password. But I don't know which password to enter. I have tried all passwords like my system login password, postgresql login password.

[image: image description here]

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html

Comment: `psql postgres -c "alter system set ..."`